# Expected estimator with exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

Given time $t$ in minutes, that is exponentially distributed with density $f(t)=\phi e^{-\phi t}$, $t>0$ and $\phi$ is an unknown parameter. Given $n$ observations $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ find the probability maximum estimate $\hat \phi$ for the unknown parameter $\phi$.

(A)

Find a numeric value for $\hat \phi$ when we have the following 10 observations:

\begin{align}\\
& t_i = 2.0, 1.4, 2.0, 0.5, 0.7, 2.0, 1.3, 1.1, 1.8, 0.2 \\
\end{align}

---

For this I have found that:

For $n=10$  we have:

\begin{align} \\
& \hat \phi = \frac{n}{\sum_{j=0}^{n} x_j} = \frac{10}{13} \approx 0.77 \\
\end{align}

---

(B)

Is $\hat \phi$ a correct expected estimator for $\phi$?

---

I have:

$E(\hat \phi) = E(\frac{n}{\sum_{j=0}^{n} x_j})= \frac{n}{E(X_1)} + \frac{n}{E(X_2)} + ... + \frac{n}{E(X_{10})}$

and

\begin{align} \\
& E(X) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \\
& V(X) = \frac{1}{\lambda ^2}
\end{align}

for exponential distributed values.
But how do I find $\lambda$?

Comment: Notation suggestion: you can write $\phi$ (with a '^' on top) as \hat{\phi}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part 1: Finding the MLE**

Using your notations, let $\widehat{\phi}$ be the maximum likelihood estimate. The maximum likelihood estimator uses $\widehat{\phi} = \text{argmin}_\phi \text{ Loss}(y_i - \widehat{y_{i,\phi}})$

Assuming some $\phi$, how would you predict each of the values? you would predict the mean. Thus each prediction you would make is $\frac{1}{ \phi}$

From here, we have
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\phi} &= \text{argmin}_\phi\quad \sum\limits_i \text{ Loss}(y_i - \frac{1}{\phi})\\
&= \text{argmin}_\phi\quad \sum\limits_i  (y_i - \frac{1}{\phi})^2
\end{align*}

To get $\widehat\phi$, we set the derivative of the above expression equal to 0, giving us:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_i  2(y_i - \frac{1}{\widehat\phi}) &= 0\\
\sum\limits_i  y_i &= \sum\limits_i  \frac{1}{\widehat\phi}\\
\sum\limits_i  y_i &=   \frac{n}{\widehat\phi}\\
\widehat\phi &=\frac{n}{\sum\limits_i  y_i}
\end{align*}

**Part 2: Is MLE Biased?**
Yes, it is biased. To see this we need to invoke the gamma distribution, as we want to take $n$ exponential distributions and sum them (note that the exponential is a special case of gamma distribution with first parameter $1$.).

Our steps will be as follows: we will first assume a parameter $\lambda$ and generate m samples. The sum of these $\sum_i X_i$ would follow a gamma distribution. Since the MLE estimate is $\frac{1}{\sum_i X_i}$, we need the distribution of $\frac{1}{\sum_i X_i}$. This follows the inverse gamma distribution. We take the expectation of this inverse gamma distribution and compare with the lambda we started with, for some fixed n number of samples.

Let us first assume a parameter $\lambda$ to generate the samples, and see if MLE returns to us lambda after n samples. The distributions are:
\begin{array}{c|c}
Random Variable & Distribution\\ \hline
X_i & exp(\lambda) = Gamma(1,\lambda)\\ \hline
\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i & Gamma(n,\lambda)\\ \hline
\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i} & InvGamma(n,\lambda)
\end{array}
Now expectation of the inverse gamma$(n,\lambda)$ distribution is $\frac{\lambda}{n-1}$. Therefore taking expectation on both sides,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E \left[\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}\right] &= \mathbb E \left[InvGamma(n,\lambda)\right] = \frac{\lambda}{n-1}\\
\frac{1}{n} \mathbb E \left[\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}\right] &= \frac{\lambda}{n-1}\\
\end{align*}
But $\mathbb E \left[\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}\right] = \mathbb E [\widehat{\phi}]$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \mathbb E [\widehat{\phi}] &= \frac{\lambda}{n-1}\\
\mathbb E [\widehat{\phi}] &= \frac{n\lambda}{n-1}\\&\neq \lambda\\
\end{align*}

Therefore $\widehat{\phi}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$